# E Series: is there any place that explains it?

Tags: capacitor, resistors, inductor, components, tolerance

So I am doing a work on optimizing circuits, and I came to study the E series of components.
I'm a bit confused and I cannot understand soem things:

- How do the tables of values (E3: 1.0, 2.2, 4.7) relate to the actual resistor values, capacitor values and inductor values. I'm trying to develop a code that maps the series to actual component values?
- Does the chosen value relates to the toleance of the components? So E3 series -> 40% of tolerance, E6 series -> 20% of tolerance... Or is it diferent? Or can I have an E3 series resistor with 5% tolerance, for instance?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I assume you have read the Wiki? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_series_of_preferred_numbers The series is unrelated to the tolerance but each series is designed to work such that with a particular tolerance it covers all values between the gaps.

Answer (score 1):

The values in the tables represent actual values of  components which is why resistors and capacitors are available as multiples of 1.0, 2.2, 4.7, etc. Each E set is designed for a particular tolerance. As the tolerance decreases from 20% to 10% to 1% and so on, the number of values in the tables increases. This is a result of the actual values in the table bring calculated so that the tolerance band of each value covers all possible values up to the next value. As the tolerance decreases in %, the tolerance band decreases so more values are needed to cover the full range.

Answer (score 1):

"The E series of preferred numbers were chosen such that when a component is manufactured it will end up in a range of roughly equally spaced values on a logarithmic scale. Each E series subdivides each decade magnitude into steps of 3, 6, 12, 24, 48, 96, 192 values. Subdivisions of E3 to E192 ensure the maximum error will be divided in the order of 40%, 20%, 10%, 5%, 2%, 1%, 0.5%. Also, the E192 series is used for 0.25% and 0.1% tolerance resistors."

See the [E Series of preferred numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_series_of_preferred_numbers) article on Wikipedia.

Answer (score 0):

Each value in an E series is a fixed multiple of the previous one.  The values are also chosen so that the numeric pattern repeats at 10.

10 to the power 1/3 is about 2.1544.  If we start at 1.0 and keep multiplying by 2.1544, we get 1.00, 2.15, 4.64, 10.0, 21.5, 46.4, 100, 215, 464, and so on.  Round these off a bit and you get 1.0, 2.2, 4.7, 10, 22, 47, 100, 220, 470, and so on.  That's the E3 series.

The E6 series is the same, but using multiples of 10 to the power 1/6, or 1.4678.  E12 uses 10 to the power 1/12, or 1.211.  Conveniently, the E6 series values slot into the middle of the gaps in E3, and similarly E12 fills the gaps in E6.

So E3 resistors would be available in 1, 2.2, 4.7, 10, 22, 47, 100, 220, 470 and so on ohms.  Similarly, a particular type of capacitor might me available in 1.0, 2.2, 4.7, 10, 22 and 47 nanofarads.

By itself, the E series tells you nothing about the tolerances of the components.  But having said that, there's little point in producing an E12 series of electrolytic capacitors when their tolerances are so large, and there's no problem producing an E24 series of precision resistors if you need them.

Answer (score 0):

The E series is **all about** the tolerance. E3 is used for 40% tolerance. Let's look at the three values and their tolerable range:

1   +/-40% covers the range 0.6 to 1.4

2.2 +/-40% covers the range 1.3 to 3.1

4.7 +/-40% covers the range 2.8 to 6.6

Notice that with those three values there are no holes in the range of 0.6 to 6. With those three values and their multiples of ten you can cover *any* value resistor. If you need 330 ohms, then use 470 instead. In fact, if the resistors you buy have a 40% tolerance, then there's no point in stocking more than those three values in each decade.

If your application requires 5% tolerance, then you need more values to cover all possible values without holes. If you examine the E24 series, you'll find that each value +/-5% covers all possible values.